# Getting additional memory on the go without pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In C++, is it possible to create a new array during program runtime? Specifically, suppose I have a data member in a class and the name of the variable is array, which is an array of size 10. Suppose during runtime I want a bigger array, can I do this without using pointers? Can I have a method as follows?

```
int[] expandCapacity(int currentCapacity) {
     int [] arr = new int[currentCapacity*2];
     currentCapacity*=2;
     return arr;
}
```

Why can't I use this method to expand the current array's capacity by saying:

```
currentCapacity = 10;
array = expandCapacity (currentCapacity);
```

If this works, there would be no need to use pointers. I feel like I'm missing something crucial here. I'd appreciate if you could point out what I am missing.

Comment: Even containers like `std::vector` use pointers internally. There's no getting around them.

Comment: Is this just an interlectual exercise or is there a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Besides, pointers are also needed in situation different than "handling chucks of memory of unknown size at compile-time". Take into account, for example, polymorphism by sub-type. A function that returns instances of subclasses of T must be return a T*.

Answer (score 8):

No, this is quite impossible.

However, doing it this way yourself is pure insanity. Use `std::vector<int>` and let your compiler implementer do it all for you.

Comment: Your wording here is quite odd. The second sentence seems to imply that it _is_ possible.

Comment: I was actually looking into how std::vector is implemented. I wasn't trying to implement a vector class myself.

Answer (score 3):

You should an STL container like a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) for example.

> If this works, there would be no need to use pointers. I feel like I'm
>   missing something crucial here. I'd appreciate if you could point out
>   what I am missing.

pointers are useful for much more than this. I recommend finding a good c++ tutorial(check the c++ [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) here for more).

Comment: I meant pointers would not be needed for this particular use, not completely useless. But I understand where I was wrong. I should've specified. Thanks